# How to conditionally add a group of props to a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a group of props that I need to apply to a component only if a certain condition is met.
So I grouped the props in an object:

```js
const props = {
  a: "",
  b: "",
};
```

And then tried to conditionally apply them to the component:

```js
<div {condition && ...props}/>
```

But React doesn't seem to be allowing this, so is there another way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should wrap your expression and then use the spread syntax on the result of that expression:

```js
<div {...(condition && props)}></div>
```

Where `props` is an object like you described:

```js
const props = {
  a: "",
  b: "",
};
```

When the condition is `false`, the `&&` operator evaluates to `false`. As a result, the spread syntax will end up spreading `false` which in object property spread is a no-op. When `condition` is `true`, the `&&` evaluates to the `props` object, allowing you to spread your object properties.